# Insert tokens for related contacts in CiviMail

Tags: civimail, tokens

Is it possible to insert tokens for related contacts into a CiviMail message? For example the mailing is going to John Smith but we would like to include his spouses name and address? Spouse is the related contact 'Spouse of'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Related Tokens](https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.reltoken) extension is currently in development and aims to provide this functionality.

Comment: I thought Fuzion had already done an extension which allowed for this, though perhaps not as completely as this new one will. Perhaps https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken

Comment: I think that could be a separate answer @petednz-fuzion

Comment: Fuzion's "CiviToken" extension adds a set of 6 tokens for each relationship type (https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken/blob/master/tokens/relationships.inc#L19); the "Related Token" extension adds "all available tokens" -- including all custom fields and other fields -- for each relationship type. (Source: I'm the author of Related Tokens).